# Creating a function to go through an array and if it finds a specific numeric value it returns true

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a function to sort through an array to return a boolean indicating whether or not the number 7 is anywhere in the array.

Reading my code out loud I feel like it should do exactly what I am asking it to do. Although I fully realize I am a beginner and I'm going to make mistakes. I cannot figure this one out.

If I input `includesSeven([1, 7, 8, 10]);` this should return true, however I am getting false as my return

```
function includesSeven(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 7) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

EDIT: I do apologize for the image and not the code.

My code for this:
[image]

Comment: next time paste the code in the editor, don't put images.

Comment: Don't post code as an image.

Comment: (Hint:try to run the code with a pencil and paper.)

Comment: your function returns `false` as soon as the first `if` statement is not `true`. But yeah post your code not a painting of it.

Comment: Please post your code in your question rather than as an image. The issue is your return false. You can also do this like this: `const includesSeven = (array) => array.includes(7)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function includesSeven(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == 7){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

in your original code, you were essentially just checking the first number  in the array, you should  return false after the for loop has completed.

while  iterating through the array, if it finds the number 7, itll return true. once its all completed, its safe to assume that the number 7 isnt in the array, so you can just return false.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function includesSeven (array) {
  return array.includes(7);
}

// or short version
const includesSeven = (a) => a.includes(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some if you want to finds the first item that returns true

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 

function includesSeven (array) {
    return array.some(num => num === 7)
}

console.log(includesSeven(arr));
```

Comment: `arr.some(num => num === 7)` ;-)

Comment: thank for the idea to make it short hand ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function myArray(array) {
      for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i === 7) {
          // 7, is found in the array list
          console.log(i, ", is found in the array list")
          return true;
        } else {
           return false;
      }
    }
    
    myArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

However, you can also use **Javascript array methods** like **map()**, **forEach()** etc to acheive the same results as using a for - loop with a **Ternary operator** instead of if-statement to shorten the code as;

```
function myArray(array) {
  return array.map(value => value === 7)
}

myArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```